# Calling a super method in delayed callback

Tags: swift

I have some viewcontroller class with the following method that I intend to override:

```
open func doneButton(barButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if let somevalue = someValueInTheCode {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        callback(somevalue )
    }
}
```

I want to implement an animation in the child class:

```
internal func animate( _ cb: @escaping () -> ()) {
    if animating {
        return
    }
    self.animating = true
    UIView.animate(withDuration: C.animTimeNav / 2.0, animations: { [weak self] in
            self?.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = C.animNavColor
            self?.navigationController?.navigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()

            },completion: { _ in
                UIView.animate(withDuration: C.animTimeNav / 1.0, animations: { [weak self] in
                    self?.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = C.navigationBarColor
                    self?.navigationController?.navigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()
                    },completion: { [weak self] _ in
                        self?.animating = false
                        cb()
                })
        })
}
```

So, I want to this new overriding method:

```
open override func doneButton(barButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem) {
    animate {[weak barButtonItem] in
        super.doneButton(barButtonItem: barButtonItem ?? UIBarButtonItem())
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is it normal to call super method in delay?
2. How can I capture `super` in the proper way?

Comment: Did you try it? Is there a problem when you do?

Comment: I've tested on one device I have. It works but I'm not sure about memory leaks and unpredictable behavior